# How does the equations resolve to the given equation?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

> $$\begin{cases}7a+b+2c=0 \\ 3a+5b-6c=0 \end{cases}$$
>   Solving given equations, we obtain:
>   $$\frac{a}{1}=\frac{b}{-3}=\frac{c}{-2}=k$$

I am confused how the two equations give the third one. It would be very helpful if someone could explain me the process.

Comment: do you mean $$7a+b+2c=0$$ and $$3a+5b-6c=0$$?

Comment: Might be best to type the equations into the problem, rather than have the big awkward picture there.

Comment: @Dr. Sonnhard Graubner: yes that is what I meant, how do I solve these to give the third equation? The answer is also there but what I am confused on is the process.

Comment: see my calculations in my post

Comment: Can you provide me the link to the post?

Answer (score 1):

Hint -

Put a = k then find value of b and c in terms of k.

You got c = $\frac{-32k}{16} = -2k$

Then we have from first equation,

7k + b + 2(-2k) = 0

b = -3k

Then,

k = a

k = $\frac{b}{-3}$

k = $\frac{c}{-2}$

Comment: Its work. You can try.

Answer (score 1):

When you have two equations in three unknowns you expect a single parameter family of solutions, which you have here.  They are giving the parameter the name $k$, but it is the same as $a$.  We can then solve the two equations assuming $a$ is a constant.  Adding three times the first to the second gives 
$$24a+8b=0\\b=-3a\\a=\frac b{-3}$$
Then substituting this in gives
$$-12a-6c=0\\c=-2a\\a=\frac c{-2}$$
Which is the result you quote.

Answer (score 0):

multiplying the first eqaution by $3$ and adding to the second we get $$24a+8b=0$$ therefore $$a=-\frac{1}{3}b$$ plugging this in the equation above we get $$-b-\frac{5}{3}b=6c$$ and we get $$c=-\frac{4}{9}b$$